# By changing MIB values(SNMPv2 to SNMPv3), new SNMP Traps are not being received

Tags: snmp, nagiosxi

I have two diffrent kind of Traps.(SNMPv2 & SNMPv3). mibs of SNMPv2 start from  ".29723.100.3.1" & other SNMPv3 ones MIB starts from ".29723.500.3.1". Now i have updated one of my system configuration  from SNMPv2 to SNMPv3 (i.e. ".29723.100.3.1" to ".29723.500.3.1"). & i have updated front end as well as backend of monitoring Server & also updated the values on Host Machine. but still it is not acquiring new configuration & i am receiving self generated heartbeat traps from my old SNMPv2 value.can you please help me out? how can i receive traps from same site.
sample trap as of now i am receiving is given below.

Sat Aug 22 2020 23:15:24 .1.3.6.1.4.1.29723.100.3.1 Warning "Status Events" 10.200.1.150 - 23610 SNMP DETECTION No SNMP Traps detected in the last=24 Hours. - heartbeatNotify

Comment: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.29723` indicates that you are working on some private objects for a vendor device, and that kind of questions can only be handled by the vendor support team.

Comment: Hello Lex Li @user:11182

Comment: thanks for your information but i am the only pone who is handling this machine.

Comment: There can be 100 root causes of the problem, and combinatorially make it hard to reach success. My advice: start from success, and modify one thing at a time to reach your solution. Eg. first generate the simplest trap (eg. coldStart) and receive it. Then make it SNMPv3. etc